# display:none; div won't show onchange()

Tags: javascript

I've got some divs that are set to `display:none;` and are supposed to display `onchange()` of a `select` menu.
Here's the html in question:

```
    <p>
        <label for="newsletter">Package</label>
        <select id="package" name="package" onchange="formupdate();">
            <option value="individual">Individual</option>
            <option value="couple">Couple</option>
            <option value="family">Family</option>
        </select>
    </p>
<div id="famnumdiv" style="display:none;">
    <p>
        <label for="famnum">How Many Members?</label>
        <input type="text" id="famnum" name="famnum"/>
    </p>
</div>
```

And then the `onChange()` function:

```
function formupdate() {
    var selectedPackage = document.getElementById("package").value;
    if ( selectedPackage == 'family' ) {
        document.getElementByID('famnumdiv').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

When I select `Family` from the `select`, nothing happens. Any ideas?

EDIT: changed to `if ( selectedPackage == 'family' ) {` and it's still not displaying that `div`

Comment: While all those answers are right about using `=` vs `==` or `===`, that condition evaluates to true, meaning there are other (addressed) issues in your code.

Comment: Error `D` , `d` and `=` , `==` , use : 
`( selectedPackage == 'family' ? famnumdiv.display='block': famnumdiv.display='none')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your second `getElementByID` is incorrect try this `getElementById`

javascript is case sensitive

Answer (score 6):

You are assigning to `selectedPackage` twice.

The third line should be:

```
if ( selectedPackage == 'family' ) {
```

Comment: True, but shouldn't the `selectedPackage = 'family'` statement be always true? in which case the `famnumdiv` would appear at every change... Which makes me think the `if` statement isn't the only issue

Comment: @Mabedan you're right.

Comment: made that change, but it's still not displaying the div

Comment: @CriketX kindly peek my answer and you'll see you aren't selecting the options correctly.

Comment: There's also the `getElementByID` typo mentioned by @EN20, which would definitely manifest itself as an error, if you had the console open...

Answer (score 2):

use this, it makes the equality much better

```
if ( selectedPackage === 'family' )
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing the code to

```
function formupdate() {
    var selectedPackage = document.getElementById("package").value;
    if ( selectedPackage == 'family' ) {
         document.getElementByID('famnumdiv').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

If you use selectedPackage = 'family' in the if statement then the value for selectedPackage will get set to 'family' with two "=" the if statement will perform a match

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `family` to `selectedPackage` instead of comparing.

Also, you're not selecting the chosen option correctly.

```
var selectedPackage = document.getElementById("package");
selectedPackage = selectedPackage.options[selectedPackage.selectedIndex].value;
```

And you shouldn't use inline js either, add an eventListener.

```
var package = document.getElementById("package");
package.addEventListener("change",formupdate,false);
```